# Android use booleans correctly

Tags: java, android

I currently have a strange problem when it comes to using `booleans` in android. I first define the boolean, but when I use it, it does not return the correct value. Take the following code:

```
public class Prompt3 extends Activity {

    boolean item1connect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt3);

        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        if (Math.abs(startcoordinatesX - itemvar1x)<touchAllowance && Math.abs(startcoordinatesY - itemvar1y)<touchAllowance) {
                            item1connect = true;
                        }

                        if (item1connect = true) {
                            indic1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ring_filled_standard));
                        }
                    }

            }

    });

}
```

When I do the above, `indic1.setBackground` will `setBackground`, regardless of if `(Math.abs(startcoordinatesX - itemvar1x)<touchAllowance && Math.abs(startcoordinatesY - itemvar1y)<touchAllowance)`. However, when I try

```
                        if (Math.abs(startcoordinatesX - itemvar1x)<touchAllowance && Math.abs(startcoordinatesY - itemvar1y)<touchAllowance) {
                            indic1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ring_filled_standard);
                        }
```

and bypass the `boolean` `item1connect` altogether, the code works just fine. How can I fix this while including the `boolean`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You miss a "=="!! You are changing the value in the if

Comment: Wrong comparison statement `if (item1connect = true)`. Use `if (item1connect == true)` instead.

Comment: As an aside, it's redundant to have `item1connect == true` any way.  You can just put `item1connect` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is telling itemiconnect to set its value to `true`.  Use the `==` operator to compare whether an item is true or false, or simply place `itemiconnect` into the parentheticals and it will check for you.

EDIT:
Where your code says

```
if (item1connect = true) {
          indic1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ring_filled_standard));
}
```

you can change this to the comparator

```
if (item1connect == true) {
      indic1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ring_filled_standard));
}
```

or better yet just use the implied true functionality

```
if (item1connect) {
      indic1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ring_filled_standard));
}
```

Java allows you to simply call your boolean in an "if" statement as it represents a true or a false value.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error "Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator"

Comment: @user3616949 use `if (item1connect)`

Comment: Sorry, I mean it worked on my second statement, but on my first statement I wrote `if(...) {item1connect==true;}`, which is where I got the error

Comment: Oh wait, do I leave the first one as is? `if(...) {item1connect=true;}`

Comment: Changed wording to improve readability.  Only use the compare on the second statement where specified.  You want it to assign on the first statement.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote

```
if (item1connect = true) {...}
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison. The return value of this assignment is `true` so it looks like it doesn't work. Just write

```
if (item1connect == true) {...}
```

Or even, simply

```
if (item1connect) {...}
```